# Artifactory simple repo artifact resolution undocumented

Tags: artifactory

How does artifactory resolve dependencies that are available via

http://my.af.com/artifactory/simple/repo

Is this repo path even documented? I can't find anything. It's equivalent of Nexus public I guess, where we can configure inclusions and exclusions to path resolution. Can artifactory do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `http://my.af.com/artifactory/repo`. This is [the default global repository](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories#VirtualRepositories-TheDefaultGlobalRepository) (and, apparently is documented).

Usage of this repository is discouraged, since it defeats the purpose of having multiple repositories. E.g. you can't separate releases from snapshots of build dependencies from build plugins.

While [you can define include/exclude patterns on any local, remote or virtual repositories](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Common+Settings#CommonSettings-IncludesandExcludesPattern) and they are all active when resolving from `/repo`, you can't define the patterns on `/repo` itself (since it's not a *real* configurable virtual repository).